Doubt about ReplaceRepeated?
I made the following code:
L={{1,2},{2,3},{2,4}};
R:=(L=(L/.{x_,y_}:>Splice[{{x,y},{x,x},{y,y}}]/;MemberQ[L,{x,y}])//Union)

When I run R three times, I get:
R
R
R
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}

Which is to be expected.

But If I make the same code with ReplaceRepeated, I get an infinite loop:
L={{1,2},{2,3},{2,4}};
R:=(L=(L//.{x_,y_}:>Splice[{{x,y},{x,x},{y,y}}]/;MemberQ[L,{x,y}])//Union)
R

Why does this happens? In the documentation, it say:

repeatedly performs replacements until expr no longer changes.

When I ran R three times in the previous code, the output was the same. Why does Mathematica understands that something changed and does it again endlessly?

L is updated every time you call R, but it is not updated while you call ReplaceRepeated, that is why that condition with MemberQ is always taking into account the initial L.

Also, in the first code, you apply Union at each step, and in the second, it will be applied only when ReplaceRepeated has finished.

Perhaps this better reflects the first code: R := (L = (L //. LL_ :> (Union[LL /. {x_, y_} :> Splice[{{x, y}, {x, x}, {y, y}}] /; MemberQ[LL, {x, y}]])))
